# How to make only one container active at the same time with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an angular js application that I want to toggle an "active" class at a clicked container and remove the active class from other containers, i.e. only one container should be active at the same time. At the moment I came up with the following code that toggles an active class at all containers at the same time. Any way to specify an id of a clicked container or is there any other workaround?

```
<div ng-class="{ active: isActive}" ng-click="toggleActive()"></div>
<div ng-class="{ active: isActive}" ng-click="toggleActive()"></div>
<div ng-class="{ active: isActive}" ng-click="toggleActive()"></div>

$scope.isActive = false;
$scope.toggleActive= function() {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive ;
}
```

Comment: You know how to toggle all as active. Why not use another variable than isActive to toggle the other two? Is this the whole code? Are you using repeats? Do you have any other identifier that you can use on the div?

Comment: if you use one flag for isActive, how you want determine what element isActive?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `index`:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <div ng-class="{ active: (activeIndex == 1)}" ng-click="toggleActive(1)">aaa</div>
    <div ng-class="{ active: (activeIndex == 2)}" ng-click="toggleActive(2)">bbb</div>
    <div ng-class="{ active: (activeIndex == 3)}" ng-click="toggleActive(3)">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:
In controller

```
$scope.isActive = false;
$scope.toggleActive = function (index) {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;

    $scope.activeIndex = $scope.isActive ? index : -1;
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/z7urh4vf/

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Can you explain what is this line doing: $scope.activeIndex = $scope.isActive ? index : -1; ?

Comment: @Deka87: It's the ternary operator. If `$scope.isActive` is true, index is returned, otherwise -1, and set to `$scope.activeIndex`

Comment: It assigns the current clicked element index to `$scope.activeIndex` if element is inactive it assigns `1`

Comment: but where you define _index_ variable?

Comment: If using `ng-repeat` it'll be `$$index` from loop, else it has to be defined manually

Comment: but in OP not used _ng-repeat_

Comment: @Tushar, you pass same index in all divs, so always active all

Comment: I don't use ng-repeat, so index has to be defined manually, that's a good remark.

Comment: @Tushar `$scope.activeIndex = index;` will be enough

Comment: Whenever I decide to replace containers with ng-repeat, should I replace all numbers with $index? (e.g. activeIndex == $index). Is that correct?

Comment: @Deka87 Yes, `$$index`

Comment: @Deka87, but this solution not solve _I want to toggle an "active" class at a clicked container and remove the active class from other containers_, if you do active any item, any next click - just do all not active

Answer (score 0):

OK, I came up with the following solution as Grundy suggested.

```
<div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <div ng-class="{ active: (activeIndex == 1)}" ng-click="toggleActive(1)">aaa</div>
    <div ng-class="{ active: (activeIndex == 2)}" ng-click="toggleActive(2)">bbb</div>
    <div ng-class="{ active: (activeIndex == 3)}" ng-click="toggleActive(3)">ccc</div>
</div>

$scope.activeIndex = -1;
$scope.toggleActive = function(index) {
    $scope.activeIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: but this also not toggle :-) just always on, so if you click twice on one element - it not toggled, but always active

Comment: For crying out loud! I will still stick with this solution for now anyway.

Comment: you can check my answer, possibly it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a few ways

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('c1', function($scope) {
    $scope.isActive = [false, false, false];
    $scope.toggleActive = function(index) {
      for (var i = 0, len = $scope.isActive.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (i == index) $scope.isActive[i] = !$scope.isActive[i]
        else $scope.isActive[i] = false
      }
    }
  })
  .controller('c2', function($scope) {
    $scope.activeIndex = -1;
    $scope.toggleActive = function(index) {
      $scope.activeIndex = $scope.activeIndex == index ? -1 : index;
    }
  })
  .controller('c3', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [123, 456, 789];
    $scope.active == null;
    $scope.toggleActive = function(item) {
      $scope.active = $scope.active == item ? null : item;
    }
  });
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="c1">
    First:
    <div ng-class="{ active: isActive[0]}" ng-click="toggleActive(0)">123</div>
    <div ng-class="{ active: isActive[1]}" ng-click="toggleActive(1)">456</div>
    <div ng-class="{ active: isActive[2]}" ng-click="toggleActive(2)">789</div>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="c2">
    Second:
    <div ng-class="{ active: activeIndex==1}" ng-click="toggleActive(1)">123</div>
    <div ng-class="{ active: activeIndex==2}" ng-click="toggleActive(2)">456</div>
    <div ng-class="{ active: activeIndex==3}" ng-click="toggleActive(3)">789</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="c3">
    With ng-repeat:
    <div ng-class="{ active: active == item}" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="toggleActive(item)">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```